# Trying to get a count from multiple mysql tables

Tags: mysql

I have been improving my MYSQL skill over the past month but have hit the point where im unsure of what to do get this over the line.

```
select id, fname,lname,status, email, country_name, login_count, 
        (select count(ID) from applications inner join players on users.id = players.user_id inner join applications on players.id = applications.user_id where players.id = applications.player_id),  (select count(ID) from messages where users.id = messages.user_id) AS '# of Messages', (select count(id) from participants where users.id = participants.user_id) AS '# of Threads', (SELECT created_at FROM messages where users.id = messages.user_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS 'Last Message Date', updated_at
from users
where type = 'player'
#And (country_name = 'australia' or country_name = 'new zealand' or country_name = 'South Africa')
and status = 'active'
and (select count(ID) from messages where users.id = messages.user_id) = 0
and (select count(id) from participants where users.id = participants.user_id) != 0
and updated_at > '2018-10-01'
order by updated_at desc
```

I am trying to get the number of applications that a user of type player has made.  Im also keen to get the number of messages and threads they have been involved in.

I can run the query fine if i remove

> (select count(ID) from applications inner join players on users.id = players.user_id inner join applications on players.id = applications.user_id where players.id = applications.player_id),

but as soon as i try to get a count of the applications made it returns this

> Not unique table/alias: 'applications'

Any help would be most appreciated.

(please be kind, I'm self-teaching myself SQL)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is when you run the subquery here:

```
select count(ID)
from applications
inner join players on users.id = players.user_id
inner join applications on players.id = applications.user_id
where players.id = applications.player_id
```

Any time that you reference a table more than once in a given query, you need to give that table reference a unique alias. This query touches the `applications` table twice, so MySQL doesn't know which one you're referring to in a given situation (and in general, you should be aliasing your tables anyway, since it makes `EXPLAIN` statements easier to follow for debugging, and makes the query more readable).

You can add aliases using the `as` syntax:

```
select
    count(mainApps.ID)
from
    applications as mainApps
inner join
    players as appPlayers
    on  appPlayers.id = mainApps.playerId
inner join
    applications as joinedApps
    on  appPlayers.id = joinedApps.user_id
where
    users.id = appPlayers.user_id
```